# speeding up the recursive function

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function below, will change the `<meta ... content="...densityDPI=250dpi" />`
so the density DPI will be reduced 20dpi each time it loops.

is there a way I can speed this up, so it does it in about 4 loops by comparing the ratio of previous values...? I think there should be a something before the `x++` the can change the 5 to something a little larger so that `$(window).width()==480` alot faster.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        $('meta[name="viewport"]').remove();
        $('<meta name="viewport" id="the_vp_special" content="width=320,target-densityDPI=250dpi"/>').appendTo('head');
        setTimeout(function (){
            var x = 0;
            var changeDPI = function (curr){
                x++;
                var sub = 5;
                if(x>500)  return false;
                var curr = curr?parseInt(curr):320;
                curr = curr-sub;
                var txt = $('<meta/>',{name:"viewport",id:"the_vp_special",content:"width=320,initial-scale=1,target-densityDPI="+(parseInt(curr))+"dpi"}); 
                $('#the_vp_special').replaceWith(txt)
                if($(window).width()==480) {}
                else setTimeout(function (){ changeDPI(curr); },5);
            }
            changeDPI(250);
        }, 2500);
    });
```

Please ask away, I will try to explain it better if this is not clear.

Comment: Can you change the `2500ms` timeout delay? Or is this needed in a way I'm not aware of?

Comment: that's not the problem, it's just there to indicate when the whole function is starting...just easier to pick up, I think this whole thing can be simplified, if I change it a couple times, and figure out the ratio at which it increases or decrease with precision, because only one factor is changing, but it's friday and I can't seem to do maths today..., I know what window width will be, I know what the dpi is, so all I need is finding their ratio of change... how many pixels of the width per dpi :)

Comment: Is it a constant ratio between pixels and dpi? Because if there is, a simple cross multiplication would do. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so let me get this straight: What you want is to set the client's dpi to a value `x` so that the client's viewport spans a width of exactely `480px`.

Now, you've got two options, depending on the relation between the dpi you set and pixels shown.

1. In case of a linear relation (which makes the most sense to me):

   ```
   $(function)( {
       var dpi = 250,
           width;

       $('meta[name="viewport"]').remove();
       $('<meta name="viewport" id="the_vp_special" content="width=320,target-densityDPI=250dpi"/>').appendTo('head');

       setTimeout(function() {
           width = $(window).width();
           dpi   = Math.round((480 * dpi) / width);

           $('#the_vp_special').replaceWith(
               $('<meta/>', {
                   name: "viewport",
                   id: "the_vp_special",
                   content: "width=320 ... target-densityDPI="+dpi+"dpi"
               })
           );
       }, 2500);            
   });
   ```
2. In case of any other relation you might want to use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) which has a worst/average case performance of O(log n). Given your 250 dpi and scaling down to - let's say - 72 dpi this would yield an average of 7 tries to find the correct resolution.
   (I'll update my post tomorrow with an example ... hang on).

Comment: No.3 is execately what is done in No.1 (`dpi = Math.round((480 * dpi) / width);`) but without the timeouts (better approach IMHO). Anyways, glad you've solved it.